# Как удалить из Git файлы исключённые в .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

1. Мною была пушнута папка (полностью) на гитхаб
2. Был добавлен гитигнор
3. Как удалить из гита всё то что под под исключение гитигнор?

Comment: http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод ответа на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047477/5441023).

Используйте [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

```
git rm file1.txt
git commit -m "remove file1.txt"
```

Но если вы хотите удалить файл только из Git репозитория и не удалять с файловой системы, то используйте:

```
git rm --cached file1.txt
git commit -m "remove file1.txt"
```

И в конце нужно залить изменения на сервер.

```
git push origin branch_name
```