# Помогите с gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Я создал файл **.gitignore** и запушил на GitHub.
Но проблема в том, что те файлы которые я записал в гитигнор уже находились в репозитории на момент пуша.
**Мне следует удалить их самостоятельно на гитхабе?**

Comment: ну ты попал в парадоксальную вселенную)))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541615/how-to-remove-files-that-are-listed-in-the-gitignore-but-still-on-the-repositor#13541721

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить из Git файлы исключённые в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029489/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-git-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделайте пуш изменений и удаляйте.